# Error while unpartitioning hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, error

I've tried to install Ubuntu (and gave up), but now there's a stuck partition, of 24.22 gigabytes.

[image: partition]

The pink shows the partition.

I want to unpartition it, but when I try to delete it, an error shows.

[image: error]

Now, I have 24 unusable gigabytes. I've tried running First Aid on the master disk, but I still cannot reset the partition.

Is there a way to fix this?

**Edit:** If I try it in recovery mode, it says "The target Core Volume is locked."

The results of `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            96.1 GB    disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data UBUNTU                  24.2 GB    disk0s4
/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +95.8 GB    disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 32D2E33F-8D67-4B7F-8CF5-ADFCB1C01C74
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Seagate Backup Plus ... 999.9 GB   disk2s2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot from Recovery (hold <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on startup), open Disk Utility and retry your partition deletion operation.

*Side note, for partitions on the boot drive, it's usually best (if not required) to use Recovery.*

**EDIT:**

To remove the 24.22 GB Ubuntu partition, try the following command **after unlocking the CoreStorage group with `diskutil cs unlockVolume`** (backups are always recommended):

```
diskutil cs revert 32D2E33F-8D67-4B7F-8CF5-ADFCB1C01C74
```

In theory, the above command should revert the partition "Macintosh HD" to a regular partition (sans CoreStorage and encryption). Then:

```
diskutil eraseVolume /dev/disk0s4
```

should remove the Ubuntu partition.

To merge the partitions, open Disk Utility from Recovery, select the ex-Ubuntu partition and click <kbd>-</kbd> underneath the pie chart. This should remove the ex-Ubuntu partition and merge it with your Macintosh HD primary partition.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but now the error comes up as "The target Core Volume is locked." How do I fix this?

Comment: Ah, it's a core storage encrypted partition. By any chance are you using filevault? Additionally, it may help if you could post the results of `diskutil list` on your question.

Comment: To unlock your volume, use `diskutil cs unlock <LVG UUID>` where the `LVG UUID` is the alphanumeric string underneath the target volume as reported by `diskutil list`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to show on the list.
There's /dev/disk0, the internal physical disk, and /dev/disk1, internal virtual disk. The locked partition doesn't seem to appear on the list.

Comment: Please append the results of `diskutil list` to your question.

Comment: @perhapsmaybeharry Removed the -1 but your solution is still no good idea. Erase volume doesn't remove the partiiton. It just removes a file system and adds a fresh one.

Comment: Ah right yes, I'm getting forgetful... I haven't tinkered with DU for quite some time. I'll edit to include the partition merging.